# What word describes whether a number is cardinal, ordinal, or nominal?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, numbers

Cardinal numbers are those which represent a quantity and generally have some unit of measurement.

Ordinal numbers represent order, such as rank on a leaderboard.

Nominal numbers are those used to identify something, such as an IP address, ZIP code, or SSN.

Is there a word that refers to this specific aspect of a number?
"Category" and "type", are too vague, and generally are taken in a mathematical context. "Use" seems to be closer, but still rather vague.

Comment: Cardinal numbers are "one, two, three" etc., while ordinal numbers are "first, second, third" etc. The former are a subtype of determinatives, the latter a subtype of adjectives.

Comment: Why do you need a special word for this distinction?  It might be, for example, that you are writing a paper on number.  In that case you would need to account also for 'single', 'double', 'triple' ... and 'once', 'twice' 'thrice'.  And then there are groups/sets of numbers: monads, dyads, triads, tetrads ...  .  These are different types of number.  In Greece, for example. the Holy Trinity is called 'Hagia Triada' - The Holy Triad.  These are different types of number.  Why not coin a word?  How about 'arithmotypes?

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question (hence putting it as a comment), but the superset of cardinal and ordinal number words is what linguists call **[numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_(linguistics))**. Alternative terms for this set (comprising cardinals, ordinals, and other terms) are *number words*, *nomen numerale* or if you prefer German to Latin, *Zahlwort*. So cardinal and ordinal are types of number word or types of numerals.

Comment: The word "**set**" is used  *The set of cardinal numbers; the set of nominal numbers,* etc.

Comment: You can use "the nature of the number."